# Does $\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x f(x-t)dt$ hold always?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

**Question**

I have found out that for many functions ($f(x)=x$, $f(x)=e^x$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$, etc.) the following expression is satisfied: $\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x f(x-t)dt$. I am wondering: does this hold always, or it is just a nice property of a particular kind of functions? My question arises from the fact that in general $\int_a^x f(t)dt\neq\int_a^x f(x-t)dt$, but when $a=0$ I have observed the equality to hold.

**Attempt of formal proof**

I have tried to prove the expression following the path of the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Given $f(x)$, we know that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ satisfies $F^\prime(x)=f(x)$, where $a$ is set arbitrarily to $0$. If we can prove that $G(x)=\int_0^x f(x-t)dt$ satisfies $G^\prime(x)=f(x)$, then $\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_0^x f(x-t)dt$. I tried with the following steps.

$G(x_1)=\int_0^{x_1} f(x_1-t)dt$

$G(x_1+\Delta x)=\int_0^{x_1+\Delta x} f(x_1+\Delta x-t)dt$

$G(x_1+\Delta x)-G(x_1)=\int_0^{x_1+\Delta x} f(x_1+\Delta x-t)dt-\int_0^{x_1} f(x_1-t)dt$

At this point the functions under the two integrals are different, so I get stuck.

**Related question**

I really struggle in finding an interpretation to the difference between $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ and $\int_0^x f(x-t)dt$, if there is any at all. Can anyone suggest a practical explanation?

Comment: In general $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$. Just let $x=a+b-t$ to see that. So:
$$\int_a^x f(t)dt=\int_a^x f(a+x-t) dt\neq\int_a^x f(x-t)dt$$

Comment: The integral $\int_0^x f(t) \ dt$ measures the signed area under the function $f$ over the interval $[0,x]$. If you take this function and "reflect it", like through a mirror, does that affect the area underneath?

Comment: @DavidKraemer I see your point, but I would associate "reflecting the function through a mirror" to $f(-t)$. It is not clear to me how the picture changes when we take $f(x-t)$

Comment: @Francesco The justification is through the interval of integration. If you use the map $t \mapsto x - t$, then the bounds of the integral can be left unchanged. I imagine mirroring the function precisely over the interval $[0,x]$. If you use the map $t \mapsto -t$, you need to change the interval to $[0,-x]$, flip the endpoints to $[-x,0]$, and multiply the result by $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x-t=u \implies dt=-du$ at $t=0,u=x$ at $t=x,u=0$ thus $\int_0^x f(x-t)=\int_x^0 f(u)(-du)=\int_0^x f(u)du=\int_0^x f(t)dt..\text{without loss of generality}$ this property is know as $\text{King rule}$ and the generalized form is $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

Comment: Which King was that?

Comment: I dont know my prof once said it was called that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $f$ is Riemann integrable,

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_0^x[f(t)-f(x-t)]dt\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1n\left[f\left(\frac {ktx}n\right)-f\left(x-\frac{ktx}n\right)\right]\\
&\stackrel *=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1n\left[f\left(x-\frac {ktx}n\right)-f\left(\frac{ktx}n\right)\right]=-I
\end{align}$$

Thus, $I=0$.

$(*)$ Just reverse the order of the terms of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Just set $u = x-t$,
so $t=x-u$.

Then 
$du = -dt$ so that

$\int_0^x f(t) dt
=\int_x^0 f(x-u)(-du)
=\int_0^x f(x-u)du
$.

This is a special case of

$\int_a^b f(t)dt
=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(g^{-1}(t))g^{-1}(t)
$
with 
$g(t) = x-t$.
(I think I have that righr.)